# In the questions involving 'the number of ways to choose' how to determine if we have to consider the order in which they're chosen?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Question: A head boy, two deputy head boys, a head girl and 3 deputy head girls must be chosen out of a student council consisting of 14 girls and 16 boys. In how many ways can they be chosen?

My approach:
I was thinking it doesn't matter if we choose the head boy first or the deputy head boys first (similarly for head girl), therefore, the number of ways to choose = $ ^{16}C_3 \times ^{14}C_4 = 6726720$

Apparently the answer given is  $ 27384 $  using $^{16}P_3 + ^{14}P_4$. I'm also confused why they're adding here. Doesn't it mean either choose from boys or from girls?

Comment: "no" does not mean "number." If you want that abbreviation, use "no." with a period after it. But you rarely need to do that - the internet is big enough for full words, and full words are better here, for the people who are not native English speakers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh yeah sorry, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

The "answer given" is certainly wrong. It makes no sense to add.   What is correct depends on whether you want to distinguish the positions of the deputies (e.g. who is first deputy, who is second deputy and (in the case of girls) who is third deputy.
If that is the case, the correct answer is ${}^{16}P_3 \times {}^{14}P_4$.
Perhaps the $+$ is a typo.

On the other hand, if you don't want to distinguish the positions of the deputies, the correct answer is $16 \times {}^{15}C_2 \times 14 \times {}^{13}C_3$.

EDIT: ${}^{16}P_{3} + {}^{14}P_4$ would be the answer if you were to pick **either** a head boy and two deputy head boys **or** a head girl and three deputy head girls, distinguishing the positions of the deputies.

Comment: It's definitely not a typo. There are four options (A)98072 (B)27384 (C)36428 (D)44389. And in the detailed solution they provided that - '+'.

Comment: @kiranpradeep Then the problem composer mis-worded the problem.  As the problem is stated, under the assumption that order of selection of the two boy deputies and two girl deputies is irrelevant, the answer is $6726720.$

Comment: @user2661923 I think that's wrong. The solution provided by sir Robert Israel seems more appropriate. Since there's clearly a distinction between head boy and deputy head boy plus nothing is given in the question regarding whether we've to distinguish between the deputy positions the answer should be $ 16 \times {}^{15}C_2 \times 14 \times {}^{13}C_3 = 80720640 $

Comment: @kiranpradeep $$16 \times \binom{15}{2} \times 14 \times \binom{13}{3} = 6726720.$$  My previous comment may have been poorly worded.  I intend that (for example) the head boy is distinct, but that the two deputy boys are not distinct $\color{red}{\text{from each other.}}$

Comment: @user2661923 Yes you're right. It seems like I made some calculation mistake. Sorry!